# prove T is continuous and find its norm.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

question- Let $x\in l^2$. Prove that $Ty=xy=(x_1y_1,x_2y_2,...)$ defines a linear map from $l^2$ to $l^1$. Also show that T is continuous and find the norm ||$T$||.

How can i show $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n|x_jy_j|< \infty$, that is what i have to prove right, to show it in $l^1$. Can we prove $T$ is continuous as implication of some theorem in functional analysis or i have to go by the definition.
And what will be  ||$T$||? please help. I did it wrong in my exam and today my teacher will ask the right solution. I don't know what is the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x,y \in \ell^2$, then by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}|x_j y_j|\right)^2
&\leq \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}|x_j|^2\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}|y_j|^2\right) \\
&\leq \left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|x_j|^2\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|y_j|^2\right) \\
&= \|x\|_2^2 \|y\|_2^2 < \infty \end{align}$$
and therefore
$$\|Ty\|_1 = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |x_j y_j| \leq \|x\|_2 \|y\|_2$$
This shows that $T$ defines a map from $\ell^2$ to $\ell^1$ as stated.
Linearity of $T$ is clear. The same inequality shows that $T$ is bounded, hence continuous. Since equality is achieved when $y$ is a scalar multiple of $x$, we can also conclude that $\|T\| = \|x\|_2$.

Comment: $@Bungo$ . Can you please answer this too.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926695/an-example-of-a-discontinuous-linear-map?noredirect=1#comment1912878_926695

Answer (score 0):

To prove it is a linear map you need to show that $T$ satisfies the two conditions

$$ T(x+y) = T(x) + T(y)\quad \forall x,y\in \ell^2, \\
T(a x ) = a\, T (x), $$

where $a$ is a scalar belongs to the Field where vector space is defined over.